# AngularJS http post 200 but not working - is data field not set up correct?

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am trying to do an http post to get a token back.  When I do it with Postman, it works and I get a success with a token.  When I do it through angularjs, I get a 200 response, but the json returned is telling me my credentials are wrong - the same credentials that work in Postman. Im wondering if there is something in the Angular post call that is causing the data field to be not understood on the other end?  Here is the code I am using for the post:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: syncURL, 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: { clientId:'anid', clientSecret:'asecret'}
            })
            .then(function(resp){
                alert("succes!");
            });
```

The response I get back is:  {"error":"Invalid Client Id or Client Secret","success":false}.

However, when doing it through postman, it works - see the screen shots with response and settings:[image: Headers screenshot]
[image: Body screenshot]

Any ideas on what could be going on or any settings I might be missing that makes postman different from the AngularJS http post call?

Comment: You're sending JSON, but with the content-type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The data should be `'clientId=anid&clientSecret=asecret'`

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly to format that way!